# Selenium IDE, Element not found regardless of how target enetred

Tags: selenium-ide, popupwindow

I'm new to Selenium IDE and currently failing to get past first base, The application under test opens a log-on window in a pop up, Username & password are entered then Logon Button clicked at which point window closes and application is displayed in Main Browser window, the script appears to record OK however on play back it fails with an Element not found error, if I use the Target Find button the field is found (highlighted yellow), if I execute the command it writes the value to the field so Selenium seem to know its there.

I've tried every option in the target drop down (all fail) and tried entering an explicit xpath with the same result. Any help appreciated.

Selenium default Target:

> id=Username

xpath obtained with Firebug:

> //*[@id="USERNAME"]

Explicit xPath:

> xpath=/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]/input[@id="USERNAME"]

Log-on window Source Code:

```
<body text="#000000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" oncontextmenu="return false;" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div class="header">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="20%"> </td>
<td class="Login">
<p align="center">
<div id="1ULogon">
<div id="2ULogon" onclick="websys_sckeys[String.fromCharCode(113)]='websys_help(\'1473\',\'-100000000000000\',\'\');'" style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px">
<form id="3ULogon" autocomplete="off" name="3ULogon" method="post" action="logon.asp">
<input id="AB" type="HIDDEN" value="4UserLogon" name="AB">
<input id="AC" type="HIDDEN" value="zzzzzz" name="AC">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<input id="USERNAME" value="" title="Username" tabindex="1" name="USERNAME">
```

**UPDATE:**

Not sure if this a false lead - the Window name is:

```
_parent
```

I came across a comment that this "is used with a frame, it will open within the inner frame"

would this have anything to do with this?

The script on the parent page is below:

```
<!--
var url='logon.asp?xxx';

function newwin(url) 
{
var 
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}
//-->
```

Then in the BODY tag we have

```
<body onload="newwin(url1);">
```

so fairly confident the popup window is named _parent but happy to be told otherwise...

Comment: Are you telling selenium to look at the popup? It might be trying to locate your xpath on the background window (and not finding it)

Comment: Yes - using waitForPopUP _Parent & I've verified that the popup is in focus.

Comment: I tried that approach in a number of formats with no success, WaitForElementPresent gives a Timed out error, I also tried a Pause for 30000 to ensure everything has loaded and it still fails.

Comment: Further info - I forced the Popup to load in Parent window at which point the script works fine so it does appear to be an issue with Selenium not looking at the popup to find the xPath - how do I tell selenium to follow xpath on the Popup - I've tried using the WaitForPopUp command.

Comment: Is the "popup" in a new window? `WaitForPopup` is intended for generic (yes/no only I think) dialogue boxes. If so, the command you need is `SelectWindow`, do your commands, close the window (if it's not already), select your parent window again,.. I'd post this as an answer but I'm not sure how to do this in selenium's native language.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions however still no joy, using waitForElementPresent I geta timeout message, Focus results in Error Element _parent not found, similarly the clickAt gives the same Element -parent not found - any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to make sure you've selected the correct window, you're obviously not looking in the right place since you're getting timeouts when waiting for elements to initialise and they're not being found when directly looking for them. 
Try confirming what window you're looking at (e.g. by search for element on the parent page, get the HTML and compare) is actually the popup.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues with Selenium either running too fast or not "waiting"forPopup. I had to

```
waitForPopUp                              30000
selectPopUp

//Do rest of code
```

Turns out forcing the selectPopUp worked to put Selenium on the correct window, where selectWindow target: name/id didn't work. To get back to the parent window after popup the

```
selectWindow
```

command then did work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that even though the popup is there, the execution of the test is too fast and the id isn't there yet (since it works if you manually execute that step).

Since it appears it's not looking at the popup, you can use a selectWindow prior to the waitfor command

```
selectWindow | <id of window> |
waitForElementPresent | id=Username |
```

Alternatively, I've also used a focus command to focus on the window(have had to do this alot with angular):

```
focus | <id of window |
waitForElementPresent | id=Username
```

I've also successfully used 'clickAt' as well.

```
clickAt | <id of window, or within window itself> | 
waitForElementPresent | id=Username
type | id=Username | <username>
```

Klendathu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions unfortunately these failed with errors Timed out, Element Not found & Element not found. Clutching at straws now the only oddity I can see with regards to the pop up window is it's name which is '_parent' - not sure if this would have an impact given it's usually used to target a frame?

Comment: Thanks! As you said the issue was the test was to fast so the element was 'not there yet'. I have added a 'waitForElementPresent' and my issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Get the ImplicitWait plugin. It automatically has Selenium wait till all elements are present before it continues to run the test. It has helped me with many similar issues